# Following anchor on another page and triggering href

Tags: javascript, html

So I want to click on a link of a page which redirects to another one that has 3 different div's which trigger scripts on their href. I am not being able to do this. I tried using anchors but it does not trigger the href...

1st page

```
<a href="second_page.html#anchor">
```

2nd page

```
<div>
  <a id="header" href="javascript:showonly('header');" name="anchor">
</div>
```

Comment: You'll need some code on your second page to check the URL and then do something based on the hash. Simply loading the second page alone isn't enough to trigger the click.

Comment: The name attribute has been deprecated in HTML5 with the anchor tag. You might want to try <div id='anchor'>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an `onload` handler in the head section of your second page which catches the hash and runs your action(s). Something like this should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function(){
    if( window.location.hash == '#anchor' ) showonly('header');
}

</script>
```

You dont need the `<a id="header" href="javascript:showonly('header');" name="anchor">` in your markup for this to work